# Probability that a real number is bigger than another

Tags: probability-theory

I am not a mathematician; I lack formal training in probability theory, but the following problem came to my mind.

I take two random real numbers $a,b > 0$.
What is the probability that $a > b$ ?
I would say, due to the symmetry of the problem, $p=1/2$.
However, once I have $a$ (whatever it is), then $b$ has to fall either in $(0,a)$ or in $(a, + \infty)$, at random. But the measure of the former is finite, while the latter is infinite, therefore $b$ will almost surely $(p=1)$ be greater than $a$. But we saw before that the probability is $1/2$. How could the mere information that $a$ exist, only knowing it is finite, change the probability? The same reasonment would apply by considering $b$.

The question may be stupid; if so, sorry in advance.

Comment: You would first need to pick a probability measure. Note that there is no such thing as a uniform distribution over reals - that is exactly why you have run into the issue of the probability of your pick lying in $(0,a)$ being $0$ for any $a$.

Comment: Here is something on a related problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem